# Expanding a bash function to add input redirection and/or pipes

Tags: bash, function, pipe, expansion

I'm trying to set up a bash function that annotates the output from commands with some prefix. Currently, I have a bunch of lines of code that look like this:

```
git pull              2>&1 | sed "s/^/   [git pull] /"
clean_cmake_fortests  2>&1 | sed "s/^/   [cmake] /"
make -j 2             2>&1 | sed "s/^/   [make] /"
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) 2>&1 | sed "s/^/   [docker rmi] /" | grep "removed" || true
```

My goal is to replace the `2>&1 | sed "s/^/$   [$1] /"` bit with a function so that I can just make the above lines look something like:

```
git pull              `annotate "git pull"`
clean_cmake_fortests  `annotate "cmake"`
make -j 2             `annotate "make"`
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) `annotate "docker rmi"` | grep "removed" || true
```

I defined the function `annotate` as

```
function annotate {
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/    [$1] /"
}
```

But when executing, it has no impact, and the commands all just dump their standard output unmodified. How can I achieve what I'm intending here? I'm going for something akin to C inline macro expansions.

---

If anyone's curious, the point of this is to let me generate logs like this:

```
04: Getting proto images
    [docker_get_proto_images] Fetching proto docker images...
    ...
    [docker_get_proto_images] Status: Image is up to date for api:dev-proto
    [docker_get_proto_images] ... Done.
05: Building local docker containers
    [docker_local_build] [sh] Building local docker images...
    [docker_local_build] [sh] NOTE: Odd behaviour may result if using outdated bases...
    [docker_local_build] [sh] Local docker image build complete.
    ...
    [docker_local_build] [sh] For advanced usage, see $ARE_TOP/deployment/docker/README
    [docker_local_build]
06: Running docker-compose
    [docker-compose] Starting docker_datacachedisk_1
    [docker-compose] Starting docker_djangodisk_1
    ...
```

rather than this:

```
04: Getting proto images
Fetching proto docker images...
...
Status: Image is up to date for api:dev-proto
... Done.
05: Building local docker containers
[sh] Building local docker images...
[sh] NOTE: Odd behaviour may result if using outdated bases...
[sh] Local docker image build complete.
...
[sh] For advanced usage, see $ARE_TOP/deployment/docker/README

06: Running docker-compose
Starting docker_datacachedisk_1
Starting docker_djangodisk_1
...
```

Which gets hard to read after a while.

Comment: You will rather want something along the lines of `annotate $(git pull) "git pull"`. The way your syntax is written, it would enable `git pull` to work on the output of `annotate` rather than the other way, since arguments are evaluated before the main command

Comment: @Alain Your approach doesn't work because the output of `annotate` is substituted *after* the command line has been parsed. Anything it outputs is passed to the original command as string arguments, not parsed as shell syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection is tied to a command, so you can't separate `2>&1` from the command it affects. You can define `annotate` similar to how you are now, though. (Don't use `sed`, though, because it's exceedingly difficult to include a variable in its command without knowing what delimiter is being used.)

```
annotate ()
while IFS= read -r line; do
       printf '    [%s] %s\n' "$1" "$line"
done
```

(Yes, the lack of braces is intentional, though not necessary. The body of a function can be any compound command, not just a brace group.)

Then call it as

```
git pull &> >( annotate "git pull" )
```

You could use a simple pipe, `git pull |& annotate "git pull"`, but that runs the command in a subshell, which might not be desirable.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Execute the commands in your function. For example:

```
annotate () {
    "$@" |& sed "s/^/    [$1] /"
}
```

Here, write the command as you normally would, just add `annotate` at the start:

```
$ annotate ls /
    [ls] bin
    [ls] boot
    [ls] dev
    [ls] etc
    [ls] home
    ...
```

Awk might be a better bet. If your `IFS` starts with a space (which, by default, it does), you can get the entire command in using `$*`:

```
annotate () {
    "$@" |& awk -v tag="$*" '{printf "\t[%s] | %s\n", tag, $0}'
}
```

Again:

```
$ annotate ls /
    [ls /] | bin
    [ls /] | boot
    [ls /] | dev
    [ls /] | etc
    [ls /] | home
```

Alternatively, you can keep the first argument as the tag, so that you can pass an arbitrary tag:

```
annotate () {
    "${@:2}" |& awk -v tag="$1" '{printf "\t[%s] | %s\n", tag, $0}'
}
```

---

```
$ annotate "foo bar" ls /
    [foo bar] | bin
    [foo bar] | boot
    [foo bar] | dev
    [foo bar] | etc
    [foo bar] | home
    [foo bar] | lib
```

Comment: `annotate "git pull"` will attempt to run the command `git pull`, not `git` with its first argument `pull`. `annotate git pull` will only pass `git`, not `git pull`, as the tag to add with `sed`.

Comment: @chepner as I said, write the command as you normally would. That is, without the quotes. That's why the example has `ls` and `/` without quotes.

Comment: I added the problem you can encounter if you *don't* quote it. This is aside from the problem of passing more complicated commands than simply a command name and its arguments to `annotate`.

Comment: @chepner If you try to execute a quoted string as  a command, that is taking on more trouble than is worth. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251103/70524

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 is relevant here. The point is, there are problems whether or not you quote it.

Comment: That puts the entire command, name *and* arguments, in the tag.

Comment: I'm following the OP's examples: `git pull` was tagged with "git pull", but `make -j 2` was tagged with only "make", for instance.

Comment: Fine, as long as you don't expect something like  `annotate "tag" command < command_input` to work.

Comment: @chepner why not? I'm leaving the stdin of the command to be run untouched. Try, for example: `annotate "foo bar" tr ' ' x < some-file`.

Comment: Bad example. `annotate "tag" command | othercommand`. `other command` gets the annotated output of `command`, not the raw output. Maybe that won't be an issue, but it's generally a bad idea to try to pass a command line as arguments.

Comment: @chepner In that case, `annotate` would used with the last command in the pipeline.